# Keep most x files and delete all others from directory

Tags: linux, shell

I found the slimier post from STO but those does not filter files with extension. So writing again.

I an writing a **shell script** to keep **last (most latest) 3** **.txt** files in directory and wants to remove all other **.txt** files.

For Example... In Directory "Home" I have following files.

1. test.txt
2. my.txt
3. image.jpg
4. test.avi
5. sample.txt
6. country.txt
7. study.txt

When I run linux script, output should be like as below....

## Keep File (keep only last 3 .txt files only)

1. **test.txt**
2. **my.txt**
3. image.jpg
4. test.avi
5. **sample.txt**

## Delete File

6. country.txt
7. study.txt

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List entries by ctime (newest first), skip the first three items, delete the rest:

```
ls -c *.txt | tail -n +4 | xargs rm
```

Comment: Yepp.. `find -print0` ? :)

Comment: If the OP's version of find supports it, I think the best approach would be something along those lines, yes.